# Why is my Unity project losing connections to scripts and assets with Git?

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine, bitbucket

I have a Unity project (2018.3 on Mac) that I am trying to get under source control on Bitbucket.

When I clone this project to my laptop, scripts and assets lose their connection in the project.

The .meta files are present in the repository, and get pulled into the clone.

Pertinent project settings:
• Version Control Mode: Visible Meta Files
• Asset Serialization Mode: Force Text

I'm really not sure what I'm missing at this point...

See the .gitignore and .gitattributes contents below.

Here is my .gitignore:

```html
# Add any directories, files, or patterns you don't want to be tracked by version control
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild/
[Bb]uilds/
[Ll]ogs/

# Never ignore Asset meta data
![Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# [Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage
*.app
*.exe

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties


# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/rider,macos
# Edit at https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=rider,macos

### macOS ###
# General
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon

# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk

### Rider ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and WebStorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/usage.statistics.xml
.idea/**/dictionaries
.idea/**/shelf

# Generated files
.idea/**/contentModel.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml
.idea/**/dbnavigator.xml

# Gradle
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries

# Gradle and Maven with auto-import
# When using Gradle or Maven with auto-import, you should exclude module files,
# since they will be recreated, and may cause churn.  Uncomment if using
# auto-import.
# .idea/modules.xml
# .idea/*.iml
# .idea/modules

# CMake
cmake-build-*/

# Mongo Explorer plugin
.idea/**/mongoSettings.xml

# File-based project format
*.iws

# IntelliJ
out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Cursive Clojure plugin
.idea/replstate.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

# Editor-based Rest Client
.idea/httpRequests

# Android studio 3.1+ serialized cache file
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/rider,macos
```

Here is my .gitattributes file (I'm using LFS)

```html
*.anim merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.asset merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.controller merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.mat merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.meta merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.physicsMaterial merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.physicsMaterial2D merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.prefab merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.unity merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf


# Image formats:
*.tga filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.gif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.psd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# Audio formats:
*.mp3 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.aiff filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# 3D model formats:
*.fbx filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.obj filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# Unity formats:
*.sbsar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

# Other binary formats
*.dll filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Comment: How do you clone? Is git-lfs installed on your laptop? Did you try `git lfs fetch --all`?

Comment: If the repository is public may be you can share a link for us.

Comment: @derHugo I just tried that - same results. It looks like something with LFS... There are png files that appear in the cloned repo but are corrupted. The meta files are there but I can't open image assets with Preview or Photoshop.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "losing connection"?

Comment: @knh190 Losing references between GameObjects and scripts, image assets, etc.

Comment: After exploration, I've narrowed it down to the use of lfs. I made a duplicate repo with the same project, and didn't use lfs, and it seems to pull / clone across machines without problem. Still not sure what I'm missing with lfs.